# Error message in google big query when attempting to create a pivot table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am getting the following error when trying to create a pivot table in google big query.

```
PIVOT IN list item must be type INT64 to match the PIVOT FOR expression; found ARRAY<INT64> at [15:17]
```

I am looking to run a pivot table to get a view similar to this.  The highest value of cohort_index is 39.  I am following a guide and the code looks very similar to mine so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Everything has worked to this point.  Do I need to cast to a type or something like that?  Not sure how to get this to create the pivot table to create a cohort similar to the attached .png.

https://miro.medium.com/max/640/1*iV4aryA4c7fczT2GHKVwCA.png

```
--- Pivot data to see the cohort table.
SELECT *
#INTO #cohort_pivot
 FROM   (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        emailAddress,
        Cohort_Date,
        cohort_index
    FROM `nexgen-362616.orders.cohort_retention`  
)tbl
pivot(
    Count(emailAddress)
    for cohort_index in
            (
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [6],
        [7],
        [8],
        [9],
        [10],
        [11],
        [12],
        [14],
        [15],
        [16],
        [17],
        [18],
        [19],
        [20],
        [21],
        [22],
        [23],
        [24],
        [25],
        [26],
        [27],
        [28],
        [29],
        [30],
        [31],
        [32],
        [33],
        [34],
        [35],
        [36],
        [37],
        [38],
        [39])
) as pivot_table
```

My schema is as follows,

```
fullname    mode    type    description
orderDate   NULLABLE    DATE    
discountCode    NULLABLE    STRING  
campaign    NULLABLE    STRING  
campaignId  NULLABLE    STRING  
orderStatus NULLABLE    STRING  
orderId NULLABLE    STRING  
type    NULLABLE    STRING  
emailAddress    NULLABLE    STRING  
firstName   NULLABLE    STRING  
lastName    NULLABLE    STRING  
ordersTags  NULLABLE    STRING  
discount    NULLABLE    FLOAT   
total   NULLABLE    FLOAT   
tax NULLABLE    FLOAT   
refunded    NULLABLE    FLOAT   
totalAfterRefund    NULLABLE    FLOAT   
Cohort_Date NULLABLE    STRING  
order_year  NULLABLE    STRING  
order_month NULLABLE    STRING  
cohort_year NULLABLE    STRING  
cohort_month    NULLABLE    STRING  
year_diff   NULLABLE    INTEGER 
month_diff  NULLABLE    INTEGER 
cohort_index    NULLABLE    INTEGER
```

Answer (score 1):

By taking off the brackets it seems to be working correctly.

```
--- Pivot data to see the cohort table.
SELECT *
#INTO #cohort_pivot
 FROM   (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        emailAddress,
        Cohort_Date,
        cohort_index
    FROM `nexgen-362616.orders.cohort_retention`  
)

PIVOT(
    Count(emailAddress)
    for cohort_index in
            (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39)
) as pivot_table

ORDER BY Cohort_Date
```